# sequencing events with visitor pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a visitor pattern implemented and it seems to be working fine but I don't see how to do some housekeeping work at the very start and the very end.

There is no guarantee of when the various overloaded visit() methods will be called so I can't tell who is the first one and who is the last one.

Basically I'm using visitor to save/load settings to/from disk.  The problem is (on loading) I need to clear some stuff out before I do any of the other loading steps.  I did put in a static variable and method to initialize things and do this load, that should ensure that something happens only once at the very start -but- a person could load things multiple times.  So at the end of the reading I'd like to reset the static variable (so they can read in again without the old junk still being there).  I can't simply put the reset into the destructor (or a method called by the destructor) because the concrete visitor objects are created/destroyed n times for each grouping of settings.

I guess I need to yolk it with another pattern but am not seeing how to.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Instead of a static variable, perhaps you can use a full blown State object that gets passed as a parameter of the visit() methods?

Comment: Not sure why visitor is ever relevant here, but try reference-counting your housekeeping data.

Comment: nm: I mention the visitor because (if I were doing things proceeduraly rather than using the visitor pattern) I could easily tell the start and end.  But in the visitor there is no guarantee that the visit() methods will be called in a given order.

Comment: Maybe scratch this... I think I can see a way to do these action elsewhere in the code where I know the order of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment above.

You could have a class

```
class VisitorState {
public:
    VisitorState() {
        // stuff to be done on loading
    }
    ~VisitorState() {
        // stuff to be done when done.
    }
 private:
    // state info you might want to keep around
 };
```

and then modify your Visitor interface to have methods that include the VisitorState

```
someReturn visit(VisitorState &state,....)
```

The VisitorState must be allocated (new'ed) when the file is requested to be loaded and kept around associated to the file being visited... It must be deallocated when (delete'd) when the processing of the file ends.

Comment: I'll accept this.  I found an easy way out because the code that actually deals with the disc is still proceedural (so I can insert what I want there).  The visitors shuttle the info from/to my GUI menus from/to the structs that I read/write to disc.  I could get downvoted for that- at least if someone else is stuck in visitors and needs statefullness your example works.